Nginx Reverse Proxy - Proxied Page Resources Do Not Load
I have a Nginx reverse proxy setup and working, but the proxied page/service does not completely load all of the remote content. I am using the reverse proxy as a way to re-configure the user-agent of the session so that the content is served a certain way based on the way the hosted service will handle the specific access request based on the user-agent.
First issue I have found is that the only way I can get the proxy to load the content is by adding a trailing slash '/' on the request... for example, assuming the proxy is hosted on 10.10.10.9, I would get the remote site to load using 10.10.10.9:83/app/. However, this has caused some odd behavior. When the remote site (proxied site) loads, all of the resources on the remote site (for example logos on the page) do not load as they are not "found." Upon inspection through the web browser (using developer tools in Chrome), the path of the file is a relative path that would be hosted on the server of the remote service. For example the HTML may refer to /files/images/image.png but when it is read through the proxy it will show //files/images/image.png.
It is behaving almost as if the proxy is not leveraging the remote service to actually process the request. I am guessing I am doing something wrong with the configuration on the Nginx configuration file. I'd love to hear someone's thoughts on this.
My goal is to make it so that the content on the remote service (all hosted in the same environment) can be fully loaded while passing through this proxy (in order to change user-agent).
Configuration file for the reverse proxy:
server {
        listen 83;
        location / {
                proxy_set_header User-Agent "Mozilla/4.0;compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1, Windows Phone 6.5.3.5";
                proxy_set_header Viewport "width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no";
                proxy_connect_timeout 159s;
                proxy_send_timeout 600;
                proxy_read_timeout 600;
                proxy_buffer_size 64k;
                proxy_buffers 16 32k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_hide_header Vary;
                proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding '';
                proxy_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires;
                proxy_headers_hash_max_size 512;
                proxy_headers_hash_bucket_size 128;
                proxy_set_header Referer $http_referer;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://10.10.10.10:83/$request_uri;
        }
}


Attempted to use Nginx reverse proxy to load remote content while changing the user-agent
